# Celery: удаление сообщений: WARNING: Celery received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, очередь-задач

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой очерёдности заданий в Celery.

1. Запускаю сервер RabbitMQ
2. Запускаю Celery (app = Celery('celery_tasks', broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//', backend='amqp'))
3. Запускаю скрипт где вызываются функции test.delay(4, 1) или test.apply_async((4, 4))

В консоли Celery: Celery received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination
и дальше тело сообщения. Content type: JSON и прочее
[image: Скриншот консоли]
Не знаю что ещё попробовать. Как получить ответ ? Потому-что скрипт так и грузится пока его не вырубишь.
Файл объявления Celery и тестовая функция. Если выполнить эту функцию из другого файла, то появляется ошибка что выше на скриншоте.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('celery_tasks', broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//',    backend='rpc://')
@app.task
def test():
    return 'Success'
```

А это файл для запуска скрипта:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from celery_tasks import *


class Tasks:

    def __init__(self):
        result = self.test.apply_async((self,), serializer='JSON')
        print result, type(result), result.ready()

    @app.task
    def test(self):
        return 'Successful'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tasks()
```

После выполнения этого скрипта появляется ошибка.
kombu.exceptions.SerializerNotInstalled: No encoder installed for JSON

Если вынести функцию  за пределы класса то опять та же ошибка с удалением неизвестного сообщения. Как я понял сообщение это то которое я отправляю когда запускаю функцию. Потому-что в очередях задач пусто. Да и в сообщении видно (на картинке).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from celery_tasks import *


@app.task
def test():
    return 'Successful'


class Tasks:

    def __init__(self):
        result = test.delay()
        print result, type(result), result.ready()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tasks()
```

Пробовал поменять сериализацию на yaml, msgpack, pickle но всё без результатно

Comment: попробуйте минимальный, но самодостаточный пример кода создать, который проблему демонстрирует: [mcve]

Comment: Это и есть пример. Функцию которую я запускаю просто возвращает строку. Или не только строку, но я все значения перепробовал. Скрипт зависает когда я хочу просмотреть результат. result.get(). Если просто print result То выводит id задания.

Comment: Я не вижу полный пример кода в вопросе. Можно просто следовать инструкциям по ссылке.

Comment: app = Celery('celery_tasks', broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//', backend='amqp') - это файл объявления Celery. @app.task def test(): print 'Successful' - это функция. Потом вызываешь функцию: test.delay() или test.apply_async()

Comment: Перенёс функцию задания в отдельный файл и возникает ошибка: kombu.exceptions.SerializerNotInstalled: No encoder installed for JSON. Раньше я просто импортировал функцию из файла где объявлял Celery

Comment: Не помещайте код и другую необходимую информацию в комментарии. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос вместо этого и добавьте туда код с форматированием.  [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему.
Поменял версию интерпретатора с 2.7.6 на 3.4.3
Правда пришлось после этого немного поменять код, а именно: перенёс тестовую функцию в файл объявления

celery_tasks:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('celery_tasks', broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//', backend='rpc://')


@app.task
def test():
    print('Start')
    return 'Success'
```

И вот как выглядит файл запуска скрипта:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from celery_tasks import *


class Tasks:

    def __init__(self):
        result = test.apply_async(serializer='json')
        print(result, type(result), result.ready())
        print(result.get(timeout=5))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tasks()
```

Зачем я перенёс ? Перенёс потому-что была ошибка незарегистрированных задач. Функция test() была не зарегистрирована в Celery().
И не забудьте поставить timeout а то ошибка будет. Даже для возврата значения нужно время.